# Sleep mode in MacOS Catalina is prevented by powerd, sharingd

Tags: sleep-wake

I am using MacOS Catalina 10.15.3. I am having a problem with sleep mode, when I check by `pmset -g`, it is reported that the sleep mode sleep prevented by powerd, sharingd. 
How can I fix this issue.[image]

Comment: hi @vietanhle! may I ask why that concerns you ? And whether file sharing (or any sharing for that matter) is on ? is power nap on, in power Saving preferences ?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this problem by noticing that in system.log, sharingd seemed to be invoked by rapportd.  And rapportd is used by HomeKit.  So I went into System Preferences, iCloud settings, and unchecked "Home".  This cleared it up.